# How to ignore the child div tag in Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I have this piece of html:

```
<div class="subscribe-page" itemprop="text"><p><strong>Far</strong> behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia.<br>
<strong>there:</strong> live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove<br>
<strong>A small:</strong> river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>
<p>The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen</p>

<div id="form" class="petersemail" lang="en-GB">

<form target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=balmpeters', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true" method="post" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify">
    <input type="hidden" value="balmpeters" name="uri" />
    <input type="hidden" value="en_US" name="loc" />
<span class="fa fa-envelope" style="
    top: 29px;
    left: 11px;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
"></span>
 <center>   <input class="emailText" type="text" value="Enter your email..." onfocus="if (this.value == &quot;Enter your email...&quot;) {this.value = &quot;&quot;}" onblur="if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) {this.value = &quot;Enter your email...&quot;;}" name="email" /></center>

<div style="
    width: 33%;
    margin: 3px auto 10px;
"><input type="submit" value="" title="" class="emailButton" /></div>
<p class="stext">Please remember to check your email to confirm the free subscription</p>

    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

that I am using Jsoup to parse it thus:

```
private void parseHtml(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parsinghtml");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
        String page_content = document.select("div.subscribe-page").first().html();

        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(page_content);
        pageContent.setText(spanned);
    }
```

The problem is that it is displaying the whole html page, is there any way I can ignore `<div id="form" class="petersemail" lang="en-GB">` and it's contents? In other words I want only

```
<div class="subscribe-page" itemprop="text"><p><strong>Far</strong> behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia.<br>
 <strong>there:</strong> live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove<br>
 <strong>A small:</strong> river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>
 <p>The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen</p>
```

Comment: The CSS query needs some tweaking: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37067940/363573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to "ignore" the `<div id="form" ...>` element would be to simply remove it from the document:

```
document
    .select("div#form")
    .remove();
```

After that you can use your

```
String page_content = document.select("div.subscribe-page").first().html();
```

to get the contents of your `div` (without the `div` itself). If you want to include the `div`, just use a `.toString()` instead of your `.html()`

Comment: Worked liked a spell! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Jsoup can also remove itself the div. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37067940/363573

Answer (score 3):

The initial CSS query (`div.subscribe-page`) can be enhanced like this:

```
div.subscribe-page > *:not(div#form)
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/%7EoW6SonaTVpso_jiZU61wWXxJMqI)

#### DESCRIPTION

```
div.subscribe-page /* Select div with class subscribe-page */
> *                /* Select all its child elements... */
:not(div#form)     /* ... excluding div with id form */
```

Comment: Nice! I opted for the *remove* version b/c it was not clear whether the OP wanted to include the `div` or not